# Nutch : org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop, nutch

When i execute nutch command to create crawldb folders and contents:

```
soporte@CNEOSYLAP /usr/local/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local
$ bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

I get this error:

```
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore as the Gora storage class.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/usr/local/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local/crawl
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
        at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:50)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:136)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)
```

I am using apache-nutch-2.2.1, hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar, hbase-0.90.4.jar and CygWin setup 2.774.

I have not hadoop installed, only hadoop libary within nutch installation hence is not a distributed but local nutch setup.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

When manually create the dir , i get another error:

```
soporte@CNEOSYLAP /usr/local/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local
$ mkdir crawl

soporte@CNEOSYLAP /usr/local/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local
$ chmod 777 crawl

soporte@CNEOSYLAP /usr/local/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local
$ bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
cygpath: can't convert empty path
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore as the Gora storage class.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=inject crawl, jobid=null
        at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:136)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)
```

Comment: It seems like "nutch crawl" command is deprecated for this version. Instead use "crawl" script, example : "bin/crawl urls crawl <url_solr> 1". [Reference here](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3.3._Using_the_crawl_script)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `-dir crawl`, you need to create the folder `file:/C:/cygwin/usr/local/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/local/crawl` at first.

Comment: I've tried this before, and i have another error: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=inject crawl, jobid=null

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace?